# I can't find "name" attribute while inspecting input elements of google form. How to find it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I have a html form from which I want to store data to google spreadsheet. I created google form but when I try to inspect name attribute to link it with HTML form attribute, I couldn't find any. I want name="entry.###" attribute. Here is what I say when I inspect an input element:

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="">
```

Answer (score 8):

### You can obtain the name attribute if you create a pre-filled link of type `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/XXX/prefill`

Right-click into one of the answer fields and select `Inspect`

You should see an element as following:

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" 
jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Untitled question"
 aria-describedby="i.desc.1567593859 i.err.1567593859" name="entry.975751923"
 value="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 4):

I hade the same issue as the OP. I was puzzled by ziganotschka's reply, but I figured out that the three-dot menu in Google Forms shows the option "get prefilled link". Then, the name attribute is shown.